# Kafka Streams : how to get the polled batch size inside the Streamer Code - High level consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have requirement to make the poll batch size as 500 and do a batch commit once 500 messages are processed. So incase of the last set where there are less than 500 messages , i need to commit once the last message in the batch is processed. Is there way i can get to know how many messages were fetched in the poll , if the number of messages left to be processed in the topic happens to be less than the poll size.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and please share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I am using kafka Stream DSL for my consumer. I have a requirement to process huge volume of messages from a kafka topic and persist them to an Oracle DB. In order to avoid individual calls to DB , i want to Batch messages(500 to 1000) and invoke DB save. Thinking of holding the messages in a static buffer keeping a counter. Once the counter reaches the limit , push it to Database. Also , keeping the commit interval appropriately high , to ensure the failure is replayed or handled.

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding comments to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Streams isn't really set up to support a use case like this, although it's often discussed under the heading of "async processing", and we'd like to design it in the future.

Right now, if you really want to use Streams, your best bet would be to wrap your DB persistence logic inside a custom Processor or Transformer, which would also buffer the records and send the batches when it has enough.

However, if you really just need to "copy" data from a topic into the DB, you might get more mileage out of using a Connector or even just the Kafka Consumer directly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what we are doing ,buffering the records inside a custom processor with a counter(say 500) and pushing them to DB. But in the scenario where last set has only 498 events in the buffer and waiting indefinitely for another two items to added. We could always set the counter to polled batch size to avoid this , if polled batch size is available in streamer code . Is that possible ?

Comment: Sounds good. No, I don't think that information is available in any way. I think a better way to do it is to schedule a wall-clock punctuator in your custom processor, so that, if the batch doesn't fill up in a certain amount of time, you can just send the batch anyway.